# Sum of hypermatrices with centered operation signs

Tags: matrices, tikz-cd

I have written the sum of three hypermatrices with the following code. The result is
[image]

I am trying to raise the = and + sings to be centered with the hypermatrices. Any help would be appreciated!

```
\begin{equation*}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=north east,fill=white,minimum width=.7cm,minimum height=5mm}]
\matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
{
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
};
\matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(2.6,2.6)$)
{
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0\\
};
\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mB.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mB.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mB.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\ = \
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=north east,fill=white,minimum width=.7cm,minimum height=5mm}]
\matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
{
0 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
};
\matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(2.6,2.6)$)
{
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1\\
};
\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mB.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mB.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mB.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\ + \
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=north east,fill=white,minimum width=.7cm,minimum height=5mm}]
\matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
{
1 & 0  \\
0 & 0  \\
};
\matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(2.6,2.6)$)
{
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 0\\
};
\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mB.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mB.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mB.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\ + \
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=north east,fill=white,minimum width=.7cm,minimum height=5mm}]
\matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
{
0 & 0  \\
0 & 0  \\
};
\matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(2.6,2.6)$)
{
1 & -1 \\
1 & -1\\
};
\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mB.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mB.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mB.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Adding option `baseline=-10pt` to each `tikzpicture` env seems to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And, why not a macro for the hypermatrix? Assuming they are always `2x2x2`, that's it.

For example, just your code adding a node at the center of the hypermatrix for the alignment you need (so you can set the baseline w.r.t. this node) and changing the ampersands to prevent problems, but converted to a `\hypermatrix` macro:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage    {amsmath}
\usepackage    {lipsum}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\newcommand{\hypermatrix}[8]
{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(center),every node/.style={anchor=north east,minimum width=7mm,minimum height=5mm}]
  \matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]
  {
    #1 \& #2\\
    #3 \& #4\\
  };
  \matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] at ($(mA.south west)+(2.6,2.6)$)
  {
    #5 \& #6\\
    #7 \& #8\\
  };
  \draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mB.north east);
  \draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mB.north west);
  \draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mB.south east);
  \node (center) at ($(mA.south east)!0.5!(mB.north west)$) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation*}
\hypermatrix{1}{0}{0}{1}{0}{-1}{1}{0} =
\hypermatrix{0}{0}{0}{1}{0}{0}{0}{1}  +
\hypermatrix{1}{0}{0}{0}{-1}{0}{0}{0} +
\hypermatrix{0}{0}{0}{0}{1}{-1}{1}{-1}
\end{equation*}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The above code produces:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can manually raise the operators with `\raisebox`. For your matrices .48 in seems to make them well centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=north east,fill=white,minimum width=.7cm,minimum height=5mm}]
\matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
{
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
};
\matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(2.6,2.6)$)
{
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0\\
};
\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mB.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mB.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mB.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\ \raisebox{.48in}{=} \
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=north east,fill=white,minimum width=.7cm,minimum height=5mm}]
\matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
{
0 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
};
\matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(2.6,2.6)$)
{
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1\\
};
\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mB.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mB.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mB.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\ \raisebox{.48in}{+}  \
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=north east,fill=white,minimum width=.7cm,minimum height=5mm}]
\matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
{
1 & 0  \\
0 & 0  \\
};
\matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(2.6,2.6)$)
{
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 0\\
};
\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mB.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mB.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mB.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\ \raisebox{.48in}{+}  \
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=north east,fill=white,minimum width=.7cm,minimum height=5mm}]
\matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
{
0 & 0  \\
0 & 0  \\
};
\matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(2.6,2.6)$)
{
1 & -1 \\
1 & -1\\
};
\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mB.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mB.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mB.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]